# A question from Selected Topics in Integral Geometry

Tags: integral-geometry

I'm referring to Gel'fand, Gindikin, and Graev's [*Selected Topics in Integral Geometry*](http://books.google.com/books/about/Selected_Topics_in_Integral_Geometry.html?id=9CUQH_NMzRAC), pages 4-5, section 1.4 (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsyKU.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHSyC.png)).

Now in page 5 they write that:

$$dx_1 dx_2 = d(\xi_1 x_1 +\xi_2 x_2 -p) d\mu_{\xi}$$
where $d\mu_{\xi}=\frac{dx_1}{|\xi_2|}=\frac{dx_2}{|\xi_1|}$

Now I am not sure how this is true, I mean:

$$d(\xi_1 x_1 +\xi_2 x_2 -p)d\mu_{\xi} = [\xi_1 dx_1 +\xi_2 dx_2] d\mu_{\xi} = $$

$$ = \frac{\xi_1}{|\xi_1|} dx_1 dx_2 + \frac{\xi_2}{|\xi_2|} dx_2 dx_1 $$

I am not sure how does the last line equals $dx_1dx_2$, anyone care to enlighten me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The volume element $d \mu_{\xi}$ itself is a 1-form that lives on the line
$\xi: \xi_1 x_1 +\xi_2 x_2 -p = 0$, not on $\mathbb{R}^2$. In the equation:
$$
    dx_1 dx_2 = d(\xi_1 x_1 +\xi_2 x_2 -p) d\mu_{\xi}
$$
the $d \mu_{\xi}$ should be interpreted as any 1-form on $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose pullback
onto $\xi$ coincides with the original $d \mu_{\xi}$. You can either use
$\frac{dx_1}{|\xi_2|}$ or $\frac{dx_2}{|\xi_1|}$ for that purpose. However,
$\frac{dx_1}{|\xi_2|}$ didn't equal to $\frac{dx_2}{|\xi_1|}$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Once you have fixed your "extension" of $d \mu_{\xi}$ onto $\mathbb{R}^2$, 
you cannot change that in the middle of an equation.